# Django DRF @permission_classes not working for IsAdminUser permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to apply **IsAdminUser** permission on my view. I am able to do it by setting the permission_classes attribute:

```
class UserProfileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser,]

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

However, if I try to do the same using decorator then it seems to be ineffective and checks only for authenticated users.

```
class UserProfileView(APIView):

    @permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
```

I want to understand why is it behaving so. Am I doing anything wrong?
My environment configuration: Python==3.7.6, Django==2.2.10, djangorestframework==3.11.0, django-oauth-toolkit==1.2.0

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think permission_classes are supposed to work for specific http methods... they're only for a View as a whole... so at best it's a class decorator and not a method decorator

Comment: It is only working with function-based views, as this decorator just sets `func.permission_classes = permission_classes`, and then `@api_view` decorator wraps function with `APIView`-based class. See examples here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/ and implementation here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/f744da74d2878b480220ebaf9d8117ff9b79a947/rest_framework/decorators.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supposed to work on `APIView` handlers, `@permission_classes` just sets `func.permission_classes = permission_classes` and then `@api_view` decorator wraps function with `APIView`-based class. When `APIView` calls a handler it does not check `permission_classes` set on that handler, as these checks are made in the `initial` method. Here is a part of `APIView.dispatch`:

```
self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
# part of initial:
#     self.check_permissions(request)

# Get the appropriate handler method
if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
    handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                      self.http_method_not_allowed)
else:
    handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to apply different permissions to different handlers (like get or post) you can either:

1. Create your own permission class and specify it in `permission_classes`
2. Override `check_permissions`
3. Put permissions logic into handlers